# set seconds minutes time interval as per customer unique id with React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to set minutes:seconds timer for my customer when they start tracker that tracker specific set for that customer if new customer start tracker then that timer start from begin and old customer tracker continue with that timer :

Example :

Customer A -> Click on button timer start -> 00:01 then 00:02 then 00:03 continue ..

Customer B -> Client on button of timer start -> 00.01

On GUI display :

Customer A = 00.03 and continue timer increase ..
Customer B = 00.01 and continue timer increase ..

`

```
const minutescallId = ( callId ) => {
            
               const caller_id = callId;
               const secObj = {
                    [caller_id] : 61
               }
               var callId = callId;
                var secs = parseInt( 0 );
                var mins = parseInt( 0 );
                // sec[callId] = parseInt( 61 );
                //var sec[callId];
                console.log("START");
                console.log(secObj[callId]);
                console.log("END");
                const minutes_array = localStorage.getItem( "callminutesinfo" );

        
    
                durationInterval = setInterval( () => {
                    // console.log("Seconds" + secs);
                    // console.log("minutes" + mins);

            

                    if ( secObj[caller_id] < 60 ) {
                        secObj[caller_id] = parseInt( secObj[caller_id] + 1 );
                        // setSeconds( { [callId]: secs } );
                        //setSeconds({ ...seconds, [callId]: secs });
                        // const newarray = [ minutes_array, { callId: callId, secs: secs, mins: mins } ];

                        // setMinutescalls( minutes_array => [ ...minutes_array, { callId: callId, secs: secs, mins: mins } ] );
                        //localStorage.setItem( "callminutesinfo", newarray )
                        setSecondcalls({...secondcalls,[callId]: secObj[caller_id]});

                        console.log("Coming seconds start");
                        console.log(secObj[caller_id]);
                        console.log(mins);
                        console.log("Coming seconds END");
                        setMinutescalls({...minutescalls,[callId]: mins});


                    }
                    else{
                        secObj[caller_id] = parseInt( secs + 1 );
                        // setSeconds( { [callId]: secs } );
                        //setSeconds({ ...seconds, [callId]: secs });
                        // const newarray = [ minutes_array, { callId: callId, secs: secs, mins: mins } ];

                        // setMinutescalls( minutes_array => [ ...minutes_array, { callId: callId, secs: secs, mins: mins } ] );
                        //localStorage.setItem( "callminutesinfo", newarray )
                        setSecondcalls({...secondcalls,[callId]: secObj[caller_id]});

                        console.log("Coming seconds start");
                        console.log(secObj[caller_id]);
                        console.log(mins);
                        console.log("Coming seconds END");
                        setMinutescalls({...minutescalls,[callId]: mins});

                    }
                    if ( secs[callId] >= 59 ) {
                        secs[callId] = parseInt( 0 );
                        mins[callId] = parseInt( mins[callId] + 1 );
                        // setSeconds( { callId: secs } );
                        // setMinutes( { callId: mins } );
                        // const newarray = [ minutes_array, { callId: callId, secs: secs, mins: mins } ];

                        // setMinutescalls( minutes_array => [ ...minutes_array, { callId: callId, secs: secs, mins: mins } ] );
                        // localStorage.setItem( "callminutesinfo", newarray )

                        console.log("Coming minutes start");
                        console.log(secs[callId]);
                        console.log(mins[callId]);
                        console.log("Coming minutes END");

                        setSecondcalls({...secondcalls,[callId]: secs[callId]});
                        setMinutescalls({...minutescalls,[callId]: mins[callId]});
                        

                    }
                }, 1000 );
        };



<div className="drag_column">
                                        <div className="drag_row">

                {calls.map( ( task ) => (
                <div className={( ( displayMinutes.indexOf( task.callId, task.callId ) > -1 ) ? 'display-block' : 'display-none' )}>
                                        <Typography className={"text-black"}> {minutescalls[task.callId] < 10 ? `0${minutescalls[task.callId]}` : minutescalls[task.callId]} : {secondcalls[task.callId] < 10 ? `0${secondcalls[task.callId]}` : secondcalls[task.callId]} </Typography>
                </div>
                
                <div className={( ( incomingReceive.indexOf( task.callId, task.callId ) > -1 ) ? 'display-block' : 'display-none' )}>
                                                                    <Typography style={{ display: receiveCallBtn === true ? 'block' : 'none' }} className={"mr-1 mb-0 " + ( ( receiveCallBtn === true ) ? 'action-button-display-add' : 'action-button-display-none' )} onClick={() => minutescallId( task.callId )}><img src={CallPickup} width="25px" alignItems="end" style={{
                                                                        marginLeft: "140px", display: "flex", position: "absolute",
                                                                        top: "30px", cursor: "pointer"
                                                                    }} alt="CallReceive" /></Typography>
                                                                </div>
</div>
</div>`
```

Please let me know where i can have problem to manage different minutes seconds as per callId of calls.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. React code runs on the client, and each client has its own execution context already.

Comment: Are you asking how to coordinate data between multiple clients?

Comment: @DaveNewton I need to give every user different minutes:seconds timer with that user unique call_Id.